# Why does my septic vent pipe cap pop off?

Tags: pipe, vent, septic

Why does the vent cap on the vent pipe that is located in our yard occasionally  pop off?  Does the vent cap need to be tightly secured?  Thank you.

Comment: If it's a cap it's not a vent. :) Has anything been modified, blocked, or damaged?

Comment: Tells me something, someplace is blocked.  Don't have any first hand experience with septic systems.

Comment: Picture of the cap will help.  Most vent caps are screwed on or have a set/thumb screw to hold them on a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

If it is Vent pipe it would not have a cap.

It needs to be able vent the drain..

If it has a cap it is not a vent pipe, it is just an access port to remove drain clogs.

Those are usually screwed on.

Answer (score 1):

Q) Why does the vent cap on the vent pipe that is located in our yard occasionally pop off? Does the vent cap need to be tightly secured? Thank you.

A) Short answer is this is probably not a vent as it would not be capped. (Unless it has something like an Odor Hog, Wolverine, Studor, or some other carbon activated unit on at the top of the pipe.)

---

There are a number of reasons a cleanout cap could be popping off, one reason is because the vent to your system (if it has one) is plugged up. Without knowing the design of your system, it would be difficult to assess the probability of this or other issues, which could case this problem. The short answer however is that if it isn't getting physically knocked off by lawn maintenance, kids playing in the yard, or other external factors, it's probably because of a gas building up within the system, and your system actually could be full or the drain field could be backing up as possible causes. The issue may be caused by something simple with an easy fix, but it could also be an indication of a much larger problem that will only get worse and likely cause a substantially higher repair bill if ignored.

My recommendation is to contact a local licensed septic professional and get an onsite inspection.